# jquery autocomplete: how to handle special characters (& and ')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

While using jQuery's autocomplete, I've noticed that characters `&` and `'` are
escaped as `&amp;` and `&#39`;

Example, autocomplete displays `Barbara’s Straight Son` but when I
choose this the field shows `Barbara&#39;s Straight Son`.

Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to unescape  the html entities. the easiest way i found to do that is to use this function:

```
var unescapeHtml = function (html) {
      var temp = document.createElement("div");
      temp.innerHTML = html;
      var result = temp.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      temp.removeChild(temp.firstChild)
      return result;
  }
```

so pass your string through this function before it gets put into your input box. You might have to modify the autocomplete plugin in order to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can set label value in autocomplete using this code

```
var temp = document.createElement("pre"); // create new DOM element 
temp.innerHTML = "Barbara&#39;s Straight Son" ; // set string which content HTML entities 
return {
            label: temp.firstChild.nodeValue, // get string from that DOM element which replace HTML entities to special character 
            value: "" // set your value here
}
```